# What is the preferred idiom in Haskell for language options vs command line?

Tags: haskell

Is there a preferred idiom in Haskell for expressing language options or other features that can be expressed on the command line? For example, should one use

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XSafe #-}
```

or

```
{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}
```

Are there any material difference between these or similar options?

Comment: I would say the `-XSafe` syntax is _a way to emulate a `{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}` pragma from the GHC command line_. Thus `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XSafe #-}` seems pretty silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{-# LANGUAGE ... #-}` is the [standard](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch12.html#x19-19100012.3) way to specify language extensions.

Comment: And is this generally preferred over, say `library.default-extensions: Safe` in a project's `.cabal`?